# ASP.NET Outputcache and Data Inside an Action Method Retrieved One Time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

Is there a way to not make two calls to a database, if I wanted to cache the request call if a database call satifies my criteria, and if not I would make that same call within the action method.  I dont want to make two calls when doing this, and would like to use outputcache.

Comment: Please post some sample code of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im making a database call in a custom outputprovider, and making the same one in the controller action method.

Comment: `OutputCache` is probably not what you want then.  Instead, look at query caching (your db may do this), or look at caching the results via memcache (or similar).

Comment: Yea I figured Id have to do this inline, just wondering if their was another alternative.